# Tree roots doctrine

Tags: php, database, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I want to get roots of tree in database, it works correctly but problem is here that it query database 500 times for 500 nodes, is there a way to improve this?

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('n')
            ->where('n.parent IS NULL')
            ->getQuery();`
```

entity structure:

```
Radio\ArchiveBundle\Entity\Category:
    type: entity
    table: null
    repositoryClass: Radio\ArchiveBundle\Repository\CategoryRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 255
        isActive:
            type: boolean
            nullable: true

    oneToMany:
        tracks:
            targetEntity: Radio\ArchiveBundle\Entity\Track
            mappedBy: category
    manyToOne:
        parent:
            targetEntity: Radio\ArchiveBundle\Entity\Category
            inversedBy: childrens
            fetch: EAGER
    oneToMany:
        childrens:
            targetEntity: Radio\ArchiveBundle\Entity\Category
            mappedBy: parent
            cascade: [persist, remove]
```

Symfony2 profiler image:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean it queries the database 500 times?  Does your Symfony debug console state that 500 queries were run?  After you get the result, is there an associated entity you are connecting to where it would have to query the database individually for each row?

Comment: can you post your entity's structure, and provide more information?..

Comment: yea symfony2 debug console shows 500 query.

Comment: Have you checked the DB panel in the profiler to see *which* queries get executed?

Comment: 500 times query to get parent entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why 500 queries?

As you say, you've fetched 500 root nodes from the database. Somewhere in the request the property `Category::$childrens` is accessed. Probably in a view by calling a method on `Category` that uses that property (like `$node->getChildren()`).

Accessing that property means that Doctrine will need to load the Collection in order to fetch the children of that node. This results in a query for each root node. Hence you have 500 additional queries.

If you need to access the children, it's wise to fetch them immediately when querying for the root nodes:

```
SELECT rt, chld FROM Category rt LEFT JOIN rt.childrens chld WHERE rt.parent IS NULL
```

This way the direct children of the root nodes are hydrated along with the root nodes themselves. You'll have reduced the number of queries from 501 to just 1.

<sup>PS: The plural form of "child" is "children" (not "childrens").</sup>

#### Nested Set model

IMHO the structure of the Category tree could be improved by switching to the [Nested Set model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). While it is slightly less performant when inserting new nodes to the tree, updating and selecting trees becomes significantly cheaper.

For example: Fetching an entire tree with the parent/children model you use now will need roughly 1 query for each level of depth (or 1 JOIN for each level, but this only works when the maximum depth is known). With the Nested Set model you can fetch an entire tree with just a single query (regardless of the depth). This will improve performance drastically when the level of depth increases.

Have a look at the [Tree behavior](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md) of the [Doctrine Extensions](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions) library, with which you can easily implement the Nested Set model. There's also a [Symfony 2 bundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle) to integrate that library.

Simply add it to Composer and follow [the instructions](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst).

```
composer.phar require stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle
```

Comment: ty for answer, can you guide me how can I fetch all entities at once for manyToMany relation like above?

Comment: In exactly the same way: add a join to the query and select both root entity and joined entity.

Comment: for example "SELECT t from RadioArchiveBundle:Track t LEFT JOIN t.tags tgs" queries database 200 times when I get results from getResults() function.

Comment: Add `tgs` to the select clause: `SELECT t, tgs FROM RadioArchiveBundle:Track t LEFT JOIN t.tags tgs`

Comment: Jasper, is it possible using the Tree behaviour extension to get all the parents starting from a particular child?

Answer (score 0):

Your parent entity is eagerly fetched and has a reference with itself.

```
manyToOne:
    parent:
        targetEntity: Radio\ArchiveBundle\Entity\Category
        inversedBy: childrens
        fetch: EAGER
```

Because it is a self reference on the fields `parent` and `children`.
When fetching a category, it fetches the `children` as well (as you would expect). But the parent entity for these joined entity is fetched as well (when they exist). Resulting in a extra queries. This goes on and on until all the parents have been traversed.

Comment: In this case it's the children of the root nodes that are being fetched (look closely at the queries in the profiler). So the `fetch="EAGER"` on the parent has nothing to do with the problem. I do agree that with self referencing associations, `fetch="EAGER"` is _not_ a good idea.